# scores not being generated from princomp, unable to generate biplot

Tags: r, pca

I am having issues with `princomp`, specifically `biplot`, when I want to use a covariance or correlation matrix not generated by `princomp` itself. For simplicity I will use a much smaller dataset than the one I am dealing with.

```
cr <- cov.wt(USArrests)
biplot(princomp(data = USArrests, covmat = cr))
```

gives me the error

```
Error in biplot.princomp(princomp(data = USArrests, covmat = cr)) : 
  object 'princomp(data = USArrests, covmat = cr)' has no scores
```

Seems like something simple going on here, but google has thus far been unhelpful.

Comment: > cr <- cw.wt(USArrests)
Error: could not find function "cw.wt"

Comment: It is a typo. It was supposed to be cov.wt(). Apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` argument in `princomp` can only be used by the "S3 method for class 'formula'". Thus, you need to specify your `princomp` call in either of these two ways:

```
cr <- cov.wt(USArrests)
pr1 <- princomp(x = USArrests, covmat = cr)
pr2 <- princomp(formula = ~ ., data = USArrests, covmat = cr)

biplot(pr1)
biplot(pr2)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! I figured it was something this simple, but it felt like staring at a wall for a while.

Comment: Although I am still having issues dealing with NA's in my actualy data set. Princomp does not seem to like to take the output from cor() or cov(), only cov.wt().