# Biplot error "no applicable method" for prcomp

Tags: r

I am doing a biplot() of a prcomp() and it gives me the following error.

```
PCARelAreaNumber <- prcomp(~ BlackSpotNumSqRt + BlueSpotNumSqRt + FuzzyBlackSpotNumSqRt + GreenSpotNumSqRt + OrangeSpotNumSqRt + SilverSpotNumSqRt + VioletSpotNumSqRt + YellowSpotNumSqRt + BlackRelAreaArcsine + BlueRelAreaArcsine + FuzzyBlackRelAreaArcsine + GreenRelAreaArcsine + OrangeRelAreaArcsine + SilverRelAreaArcsine + VioletRelAreaArcsine + YellowRelAreaArcsine, data = AmyRawData, scale = TRUE)

biplot(PCARelAreaNumber, col = c("white", "red"))
Error in UseMethod("biplot") : 
    `enter code here`no applicable method for 'biplot' applied to an object of class "prcomp"

biplot(PCARelAreaNumber)
Error in UseMethod("biplot") : 
   no applicable method for 'biplot' applied to an object of class "prcomp"
```

This is weird because it was working a few weeks ago. I am using the latest version of R and R Studio.

I found one suggestion for princomp() where the problem was the formula:
[scores not being generated from princomp, unable to generate biplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752899/scores-not-being-generated-from-princomp-unable-to-generate-biplot)

I am fairly sure my formula input format is correct. Any thoughts?

Comment: I figured out the problem. Somewhere along the way, I managed to add biplot() to my Functions (shown in R Studio). Likely, there was something funny in whatever I had as a Function. I removed the function and biplot() now recognizes the prcomp object.